# C# language theory question

Tags: c#

Given the following method,where I pass configuration byref, then loop through it using a foreach named collection. In the following code sample, will the values that I change in the loop be updated in the main object I passed through by ref, what I mean is NO shallow copies? Or can you spot any mistake I've made.

More specifically the line where I call config.Value = ..... the configuration object has a collection of configurations, so will these be updated in the main object (configuration) after this function is called?

Thanks in advance.

```
public static void DecryptProviderValues(ref MyConfiguration configuration)
    {
        foreach (var provider in configuration.Providers)
        {
            var configItems = provider.Configurations;
            foreach (Configuration config in configItems)
            {
                if(EncryptionManager.IsEncrypted(config.value))
                {
                    config.Value = EncryptionManager.Decrypt(config.Value);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: foreach makes the collection immutable, unless the updates to the collection takes place after the execution of the loop, like in using NHibernate and flushing after we are done with the loop. Thanks

Comment: @Mahesh Velaga: the collection *itself* is never modified, so while that is *true*, it is unrelated.

Comment: @Marc: I really want to know more about that, can you please point me towards a good reference that deals about changing collections in foreach and also when are they modified and when they are not. Thanks :)

Comment: Mahesh, start by reading the documentation; it clearly states that modifying a collection while enumerating it causes undefined behaviour: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that all the items here are **classes** (not structs), then yes, but actually there is **no need** for `configuration` to be passed as `ref`; you are **already** passing a reference (by value), and you aren't *re-assigning* the reference, so no need for `ref` here **at all**. Your changes are preserved and available to the caller.

For exactly the same reason that this would work:

```
Configuration x = new Configuration();
Configuration y = x;
x.Value = "abc";
Console.WriteLine(y.Value); // writes "abc"
```

here, because `Configuration` is (presumably) a `class`, there is **only** one object, and two variables that *refer* to the same object (at a simplified level, they are glorified pointers to the same object).

Comment: Thank you Marc, just to clarify, if I don't pass this object by ref, this object will still be updated globally in any calling methods?

Comment: Yes. Without `ref` this is still available. The only time you'd need `ref` (with classes) is if *inside* the method you had `configuration = ...;` (i.e. you *reassign* the variable), and you want this reassignment to be visible to the caller.

Comment: @JL: Yes if it is a reference type as the reference is pointing to the instance on the heap. It doesn't make any difference if you access the instance through a copy of the reference itself.

Comment: In the context of the original question, it is only `struct` that becomes a shallow copy, and `struct` should be imutable for *exactly* the reason of avoiding lost changes.

Comment: @JL - Unlike C++, C# does not copy objects when you pass them as parameters. If you are coming from C++, think of variables to objects as pointers and you are always passing pointers.

Comment: @tgiphil - as long as it is a *reference type* (`class`, `interface`, `delegate`)

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to pass `configuration` by `ref` in your case, since in C# you're manipulating references to instances of classes already.

You would use `ref` to pass value types like `int` or `struct` by reference.